# Unexpected token in JSON at position 0

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I'm trying to read a .json file with fs and parse to a JavaScript object using JSON.parse() function.

```js
const json = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('./db.json', (err) => { if (err) throw err; }))
```

```js
{
  "hello": "world"
}
```

But I'm getting the following error:

> undefined:1 { ^ SyntaxError: Unexpected token  in JSON at position 0

Does anyone know what's wrong?

Comment: Side note: `json` isn't a great name for a variable that doesn't contain JSON. Remember that JSON is a *textual notation* for data exchange. [(More here.)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2904181/157247) If you're dealing with JavaScript source code, and not dealing with a *string*, you're not dealing with JSON.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`readFileSync`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfilesync_path_options) returns a [**`Buffer`**](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_class_buffer) if you don't tell it what encoding to use to convert the file contents to text. If you pass a `Buffer` into `JSON.parse`, it'll get converted to string before being parsed. `Buffer`'s [`toString`](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buf_tostring_encoding_start_end) defaults to UTF-8.

So there are a couple of possible issues:

1. The file isn't in UTF-8
2. It is, but it has a [byte order mark](https://www.unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html#bom1) (BOM) on it *(which is slightly unusual — UTF-8 has a fixed byte order — but there is one defined and sometimes files have it as an indicator they're in UTF-8)*

Separately from that, `readFileSync` doesn't accept a callback (it returns its result or throw an error instead, because it's synchronous — that's what the `Sync` suffix means in the Node.js API). (If it **did** have a callback, doing `throw err` in that callback would be pointless. it wouldn't, for instance, throw an error from the function where you're calling `readFileSync`.)

If the file isn't UTF-8, tell `readFileSync` what encoding to use (I suggest always doing that rather than relying on implicit conversion to string later). If it's in (say) UTF-16LE ("UTF-16 little endian"), then you'd do this:

```
const data = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('./db.json', "utf16le"));
```

If it's in UTF-8 with a BOM: `Buffer` doesn't remove the BOM when it converts to string, so you end up with what looks like a weird character at position 0 which `JSON.parse` doesn't like. If that's the case, you can do this:

```
const UTF8_BOM = "\u{FEFF}";
let json = fs.readFileSync('./db.json', "utf8");
if (json.startsWith(UTF8_BOM)) {
    // Remove the BOM
    json = json.substring(UTF8_BOM.length);
}
// Parse the JSON
const data = JSON.parse(json);
```